# Parse Push Notifications are sent from a server but not received by a client

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

My goal is to have a user send a push notification to another user.

To fire my push notification, I load some data into a hash map, and send it off to some Cloud Code which will then validate the data and forward it to the target user.  I checked server logs and I can verify that that the Cloud Code properly receives the data and sends off a successful request, however, my broadcast receiver never picks up the data sent to the target user.  I did test that if I send the push notification directly from Parse, filtering by the facebookId, then the device will receive the push notification.

I followed this tutorial: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-dangerous-world-of-client-push/

Here is my client side sending code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> parseQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
parseQuery.whereEqualTo("facebookId", userId);
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
try {
        ParseUser matchUser = parseQuery.getFirst();
        params.put("name", matchUser.getString("name"));
        params.put("recipientId", matchUser.getObjectId());
        params.put("facebookId", matchUser.getString("facebookId"));
        params.put("startDate", new Date(matchEvent.getLong("startDate")).toString());
        params.put("endDate", new Date(matchEvent.getLong("endDate")).toString());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
      Log.e("MatchTimesArrayAdapter", "The match user is null");
    }

ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("validatePush", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void done(String s, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // Push sent successfully
            Toast.makeText(context, "Request sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
});
```

Here is my Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("validatePush", function(request, response) {
    var senderUser = request.user;
    var senderName = request.params.name;
    var recipientId = request.params.recipientId;
    var recipientUserId = request.params.facebookId;
    var startDate = request.params.startDate;
    var endDate = request.params.endDate;
    var message = senderName + " would like to meet with you from " + startDate + " to " + endDate + ".";

    if (senderUser.get("FriendsList").indexOf(recipientUserId) === -1) {
        response.error("The recipient is not the sender's friend, cannot send push");
    }
    var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
    recipientUser.id = recipientId;
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.equalTo("user", recipientUser);

    Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
            alert: message
        }
    }).then(function() {
        response.success("Request was sent successfully.");
    }), function(error) {
        response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
    };
});
```

Here is my Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class ExerciseRequestBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int notificationId = 51;
    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
        // replace openAppIntent with event modification
        Intent openAppIntent = new Intent(context, MatchesActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MatchesActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(openAppIntent);
        PendingIntent acceptIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent declineIntent = null;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_login)
                .setContentTitle("Fiternity")
                .setContentText(intent.getDataString())
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add, "Accept", acceptIntent)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_input_delete, "Decline", declineIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("ReceiverIssue", "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

I have a hunch that it has to do with how I store data within the ParseInstallation.  I have the facebookId saved to a particular ParseInstallation, but I have a separate table with User objects in it.  Do I need to save the ParseUser objects to the ParseInstallation?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up attempting to use the Parse User or Parse Installation as IDs and used the Facebook ID instead to get Push Notifications working.

```
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.equalTo("facebookId", recipientId);
```

Comment: any idea whats the issue ? if i m not using faceBook id then how can i do i have just resgiter user using Parse not from FB her eis my code it is not workign http://pastie.org/10224504

Comment: Use Parse Installation's ID to register users.
`Parse.initialize(this);

        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to subscribe for push notifications.");
                }
            }
        });
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();`